# How to find where a Cisco CSS VIP is pointing to?

Tags: cisco, css

I'm wondering if there's a way to find out where a Cisco CSS VIP is pointing to without access to the Cisco switch?

Let's say VIP 192.168.1.10:80 can be possibly pointing to ServerA:10000 or ServerB:1000. How can I find which of the two servers I'm connected to? Any 3rd party or freeware utility I can use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have access to the Cisco CSS, then you might have access to the switches on the path from Cisco CSS to the servers, or on the servers.

You can configure a SPAN port (traffic mirroring on a port) on a Cisco switch, or you can check the access logs, or `netstat -an` of the servers.